# Fast string-to-integer algorithm

Tags: integers, base-conversion

I work with big integers that I need to convert to and from strings, and to and from different bases.

In JavaScript, BigInt allows to convert an integer to a string in a chosen base by doing:

```js
12345n.toString(9)
```

Unfortunately, when parsing a string to convert it to an integer, BigInt only accepts bases 2, 8, 10, and 16. It isn't possible to parse with a base of 9 (there is [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-number-fromstring) for this, but it's not getting much traction).

So, I've written the algorithm myself:

```js
const ALPHABET = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
const fromString = (text, base) => {
    let result = 0n;

    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        result = result * base + BigInt(ALPHABET.indexOf(text.charAt(i)));
    }

    return result;
};
```

It works correctly, but it's very slow.

For example, with the number `1×10^500,000` (a string containing a `1` followed by `500,000` zeros):

- `BigInt(str)` takes about 50ms on my machine
- `fromString(str, 10n)` takes 15s, 300 times longer!

The fact that BigInt is implemented in C++ is not enough to explain this enormous difference, I believe.

The algorithm must be much more efficient. It seems to be `FromStringLarge`, [in V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/src/bigint/fromstring.cc). However, I do not understand how it works and I didn't find any other references to this algorithm.

**Would someone be able to explain the `FromStringLarge` algorithm, or suggest another algorithm?**

Comment: There is a very large docstring just before the code of `FromStringLarge`. Have you read it?

Comment: Thanks Yuval. Yes I have, many times before asking the question, and many times after... I finally succeeded to understand what I was missing, I implemented it in JS, and it works very well: 100ms to convert `1×10^500,000`. I don't understand very well yet why it's faster, but at least my problem is solved. (Note: I'm waiting for Kenneth's reply, and I'll post my version of the algorithm in JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a string of length $n$, your own algorithm will loop $n$ times, and each addition grows in the order of $O(n)$, yielding a total of $O(n^2)$.

`result = result * base + digit`

With length $n = 10^6$, in the beginning we add one single-digit number, in the end we add one million-digit number, yielding $1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n^2$ single-digit operations.

Instead, using the efficient `FromStringLarge` divide-and-conquer algorithm, we may accomplish $O(n \log n)$. How might this be achieved? According to the documentation: Multiply-and-add neighboring pairs of parts, then loop, until only one part is left.

`result = left * multiplier + right`

With length $n = 10^6$, in the beginning we add one million single-digit numbers, in the end we add one million-digit number, yielding $n * 1 + n / 2 * 2 + n / 4 * 4 + ... + 1 * n = n \log n$ single-digit operations.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, but could you elaborate on your last sentence? I don't understand how the algorithm you describe works. Is it the same as `FromStringLarge` from V8? Note: I finally succeeded to understand and implement in JS `FromStringLarge`, and it works very well: 100ms to convert `1×10^500,000`! I don't understand very well yet why it's faster, but at least my problem is solved.

Comment: @Zwyx my algorithm was incorrect, even though i initially thought it's simpler and faster. for example when converting ZZZZ from base 36 to base 10, it's incorrectly producing 35 * 10^3 _+ 35 * 10^2 + 35 * 10^1 + 35, instead of the correct 35 * 36^3 + 35 * 36^2 + 35 * 36^1 + 35. it's not the same as FromStringLarge from V8 that uses divide and conquer to achieve O(n log n) time complexity. i've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. It's still not super clear to me, but it might be above my level so I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Zwyx Thanks, but I'm curious which part do you still not understand? (especially since you've implemented it correctly, and you originally correctly pointed out my mistake). I've looked at your solution, and the best intuition for why it's faster, is that it rarely does the lengthy addition of result += something. It only processes smaller parts. You can try to analyze the amount of calculation in each line of code. The difference in this case is very similar from to the difference of what bubble sort does and what merge sort does, which you can review carefully.

Comment: I think this is wrong: `1+2+3+...+n=n2`, but I understand what you mean anyway (it grows exponentially).
However, I don't understand this bit: `in the beginning we add one million single-digit numbers, in the end we add one million-digit number` (as well as the following formula). I don't succeed to make the connection between this sentence and the relevant part in the algorithm.

Comment: @Zwyx looking at the docstring itself, in the first iteration, it calculates 16 single-digit operations, and in the last iteration, it calculates one 16-digit operation. do you think this idea holds?

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding an answer to share my rough JavaScript version of V8's `FromStringLarge` algorithm:

```typescript
const fromBase = (text: string, base: bigint): bigint => {
    let parts = text.split("").map((part) => [BigInt(part), base]);

    if (parts.length === 1) {
        return parts[0][0];
    }

    let pairFull: boolean;
    while (parts.length > 2) {
        pairFull = false;
        parts = parts.reduce<bigint[][]>((acc, cur, i) => {
            if (!pairFull) {
                if (i === parts.length - 1) {
                    acc.push(cur);
                } else {
                    acc.push([
                        cur[0] * parts[i + 1][1] + parts[i + 1][0],
                        cur[1] * parts[i + 1][1],
                    ]);
                    pairFull = true;
                }
            } else {
                pairFull = false;
            }
            return acc;
        }, []);
    }

    return parts[0][0] * parts[1][1] + parts[1][0];
};
```

It now takes 120ms to do the conversion a string containing 500,000 random digits in base 10! Just slightly slower than BigInt, and without any optimisations.

Comment: We're not a coding site, and we're not particularly looking for answers that consist primarily of a big chunk of code.  Can you [edit] your answer to explain the main ideas, provide concise pseudocode, explain the answer to the original question, etc.?

Comment: I've only added this answer to provide my JS version of the algorithm, all the info about the algorithm is already present in the answer I accepted and the comments below, I don't want to reappropriate to myself what Kenneth has written, and this was too big to fit in a comment. Feel free to delete it.

Comment: Got it.  It would help to add to your answer that this is an implementation of the algorithm in [Kenneth Kho's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/164765/755).